# How to write an Alexa skill that does not display any card

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-fire-tv

I am writing a skill to use on my **Amazon Fire TV Cube**. The skill has simple commands. For example, "*Alexa, ask Cinema (skill name) to set volume to 50*". The skill handler sends a simple `HTTP GET` command to a server and returns a simple .speak response "*setting volume to 50*".

My problem is that it also displays a card with the skill name that stays for a few seconds. It basically says "*Cinema (skill name) To quit, try "Alexa, exit.*" Obviously, if I am watching a movie, this is annoying. I looked everywhere in the Alexa documentation, but it only tells how to customize and write nicer cards, but not how to avoid displaying anything.

My question is whether there is something to invoke a different method or different parameters to `ResponseBuilder` so that it only speaks and doesn't display anything.

This is the skill handler code:

```
const SetVolumeIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'SetVolumeIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        const my_vol = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.volume.value;
        const speechText = 'setting volume to ' + my_vol;
        httpGet(my_ip, my_port, '/process_command?command=set_volume&volume=' + my_vol, (theResult) => {});
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .getResponse();
    }
};
```

httpGet is a function that does what it sounds like. Note that it does the work itself (volume is changed). My problem is simply how to stop it from displaying anything and simply do the work in the background.

This is the JSON output that I get in the Alexa test environment:

```
{
    "body": {
        "version": "1.0",
        "response": {
            "outputSpeech": {
                "type": "SSML",
                "ssml": "<speak>setting volume to 50</speak>"
            },
            "type": "_DEFAULT_RESPONSE"
        },
        "sessionAttributes": {},
        "userAgent": "ask-node/2.3.0 Node/v8.10.0"
    }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: For custom skills, I don't believe there is a way to change this behaviour. Your code is correct for sending a response without a custom card - but you still get the default card (which is what you are seeing).

You could look at creating a custom skill instead, and use the _Alexa.Speaker Interface_ - https://developer.amazon.com/docs/device-apis/alexa-speaker.html

This might be better for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a **Fire TV Cube** as you do but here is my test **result** in simulator
[image: medium hub simulator capture]

and this is the corrsponding code.

```
handle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(`Hello World!`)
            .withSimpleCard(null)
            .getResponse();
}
```

Please check it in your fire TV and update the status as I'm really looking forward to it. Thanks.